# Getting Cannot read property 'type' of null topojson

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm trying to implement my first map in topojson.
I converted shape file to GeoJson and then into topojson.

When I run the bellow code I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null` error on `D3.js` file.

```
var width = 960,
      height = 1160;

  var svg = d3.select("#visualize").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-20, 0, 20, 40])
    .range(["blue", "green", "yellow", "red"]);



  d3.json(base_url+"assets/m4k/party_perfomance/lok15_final.json", function(error, lok) {
        console.log(lok)
        var subunits = topojson.feature(lok, lok.objects.lok15);

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                                    .scale(500)
                                    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(subunits)
            .attr("d", path);
  });
```

You can check the code and topojson file here

http://tributary.io/inlet/5636305

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use datum to append an element, you can just append it:

```
svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', path(subunits[0]));
```

If you want to bind the features to the path elements, use this instead:

```
svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(subunits)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path);
```

Comment: Even If I add path like this its not showing any thing, This is my first time so i'm not sure if my topojson is wrong or my code.

Comment: I tested your code Using selectAll and I don't get the TypeError. Have you tried with the geojson file? Check this tutorial http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/